# Installing VB6 app causes IE6 errors?

Tags: javascript, vb6, internet-explorer-6

I have a VB 6 app that I've inherited, and made some small updates to, but now when it is scripted to install (for SMS, using BITS_INST.exe) and I install it from that script, I get the following javascript error on our portal on links that are attempting to open new windows:

Error: 'window.open(...)' is null or not an object

This app never caused this problem before.  It's been installed for years, and was updated just about a year ago without a problem.

Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: What does that app install? Can you really tie the problem to your app?

Answer (score 0):

Some problem solving tips to try:

- Is it possible to uninstall the app? Does that make Javascript work again?
- Does the VB app make changes to the registry, or system files?
- Does this problem happen when installed on another computer?
- Does this problem happen on another computer without the VB app installed?
- Does this problem happen on a    different browser?
- Is it coincidence? Has your Portal    code been changed?
- Are you able to compare the current VB app's code with a previous version?  What's changed?
- Is it possible to do what you want a different way?

In my experience if you ask enough questions, and experiment with different scenarios, you'll usually discover what the problem is.

Answer (score 0):

Jonathan, thank you for your reply.

You posted many of the questions anyone should ask while debugging an unexpected behavior, and I did most of them before posting my question.

This problem was resolved.  The person who was building the install script discovered that the bits_inst.exe was getting corrupted.  When she was able to correct the problem and build so that there was no corruption, then the installed app did not affect IE adversely.
I had a strong feeling that the app wasn't the cause, and it wasn't, but had to look at all possbile sources of the offending IE behavior.

Again, thanks for your response.

Brian Sherwood
Houston, tx